# Mysql complex joins using IF

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to add some join statements for my query with if condition. I tried to use CASE func. but it only returns an expression. What I want to query is;

```
SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON (table1.id = table2.id)
IF(table1.col1 like '%a%')
 {
   JOIN table3 ON .....
   LEFT JOIN table4 ON ....
   .....
 }
ELSE
 {
   JOIN table5 ON ....
   LEFT JOIN table6 ....
 }
WHERE 
 ......
```

Is there any way to create a query like this?

Comment: This kind of problem can be symptomatic of poor design

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: Yes , you can but not using by if's..you need to add the IF condition to the ON clause of the join, this way when the condition is true, this columns will have values and when the condition is not true, they will be nulls.

```
SELECT * FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON (table1.id = table2.id)
JOIN table3 ON(table1.id = table3.id AND table1.col like '%a%')
LEFT JOIN table4 ON(table1.id = table4.id AND table1.col like '%a%')
JOIN table5 ON(table1.id = table5.id AND table1.col not like '%a%')
LEFT JOIN table6 ON(table1.id = table6.id AND table1.col not like '%a%')
```

You can't divide your table and connect few rows to 1 table and another rows to another.. So thats the best way I could think of.

Comment: Does this work even when table1.col contains NULL's?

Comment: @jarlh Well, I didn't think he would have this possibility.. hellzone if thats the case tell me and I'll update the answer although I assume its not..

Comment: @sagi No. table1.col doesn't have null values.

Comment: Then thats your answer @hellzone